# Spring Integration DSL ScatterGather flow blocks

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have an integration flow that does a scatter gather operation which hits multiple HTTP endpoints returning JSON. Then aggregates the result into a single JSON object. The flow goes like this

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow(IMyService myService, IMyOtherService myOtherService) {
return f -> f.enrichHeaders(eh -> eh.headerExpression(Headers.PAYLOAD, "payload"))
             .handle(HeaderPrinter::headerPrinter)
             .enrichHeaders(httpRequestHeaderEnricher())
             .scatterGather(
                scatterer -> scatterer.recipientFlow(sf -> sf.enrichHeaders(he -> he.header(Headers.DATA_ENDPOINT, "endpoint1"))
                                                             .handle(createOutboundHttpGateway(baseUrl, httpRequestFactory)))
                                      .recipientFlow(sf -> sf.enrichHeaders(he -> he.header(Headers.DATA_ENDPOINT, "endpoint2"))
                                                             .handle(createOutboundHttpGateway(baseUrl, httpRequestFactory)))
                                      .applySequence(true),
                gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(MyFlows::aggregateJsonFromMultipleSources)
            )
            .handle(myService, "handleAggregatedJson")
            .handle(HeaderPrinter::headerPrinter)
            .handle(myOtherService, "handleMyServiceOutput")
            .channel("myFlow.output");
}
```

I'm starting the flow using a gateway declared as follows

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface IMyGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "myFlow.input", replyChannel = "myFlow.output")
    MyResult startFlow(@Payload String payload, @Header("header1") String header1, @Header("header2") String header2);

}
```

The problem I have is that the whole flow blocks and the gateway times-out. I've put breakpoints in the two service calls **IMyService::handleAggregatedJson** and **IMyOutherService::handleMyServiceResult** and they are both running, but the output never reaches the reply channel of the gateway. If I remove both of the last two **handle** operations then the flow returns a result normally via the gateway.

I've looked into the stack-trace while the flow is blocked and I can see that the thread running the flow is waiting on a lock

> java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING   at
>   sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
>   at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231) 
>   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel.receive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:308)
>   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel.receive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:300)
>   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:201)
>   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:234)
>   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
>   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>   at
>   org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
>   at
>   org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38)
>   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:95)
>   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:85)
>   at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:487)
>   at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:461)
>   at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:520)
>   at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:469)
>   at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:460)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.startFlow(Unknown Source:-1)

From what I suspect if the flow takes more than X time then it will block. I tried putting a rendezvous channel between the flow and the gateway but it didn't seem to work.

Any ideas on what's causing the timeout problem?

Addendum: I've been fiddling a bit with the code and removing the return type on the Gateway and the last .channel call on the flow does seem to stop blocking it.

The following works fine

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow(IMyService myService, IMyOtherService myOtherService) {
return f -> f.enrichHeaders(eh -> eh.headerExpression(Headers.PAYLOAD, "payload"))
             .handle(HeaderPrinter::headerPrinter)
             .enrichHeaders(httpRequestHeaderEnricher())
             .scatterGather(
                scatterer -> scatterer.recipientFlow(sf -> sf.enrichHeaders(he -> he.header(Headers.DATA_ENDPOINT, "endpoint1"))
                                                             .handle(createOutboundHttpGateway(baseUrl, httpRequestFactory)))
                                      .recipientFlow(sf -> sf.enrichHeaders(he -> he.header(Headers.DATA_ENDPOINT, "endpoint2"))
                                                             .handle(createOutboundHttpGateway(baseUrl, httpRequestFactory)))
                                      .applySequence(true),
                gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(MyFlows::aggregateJsonFromMultipleSources)
            )
            .handle(myService, "handleAggregatedJson")
            .handle(HeaderPrinter::headerPrinter)
            .handle(myOtherService, "handleMyServiceOutput")
            .handle(m -> {
                log.info("Flow completed successfully, payload as expected:" + payload);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if all your

```
.handle(myService, "handleAggregatedJson")
.handle(HeaderPrinter::headerPrinter)
.handle(myOtherService, "handleMyServiceOutput")
```

after gathering return some value. Typical error with request-reply that some step in the flow stops to reply with some reasonable value.

**UPDATE**

You should consider to remove explicit `replyChannel` declaration from the `@Gateway` definition and also remove `.channel("myFlow.output")` from the end of flow.  This way you should get a reply to the `replyChannel` header. When you configure explicit `replyChannel`, there is no guarantee that you won't have some other subscriber to this channel which is going to "steal" your reply messages.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-default-reply-channel).

Comment: Yes they all do. It seems to be a timing issue, when I run on debug mode I have to remove all the .handle calls for the flow to complete.

Comment: By default the `@MessagingGateway` waits indefinitely. See its `defaultReplyTimeout`.

Comment: Well, if you have to remove them for the testing purpose, then definitely there is something wrong with one of them and it just returns `null` which is a signal do not continue a flow.

Comment: I've put breakpoints into all the **handle** callbacks and they all get called and return an actual object, not null. The call that seems to make the whole flow block is the ending one to **channel**. If I remove that the flow completes successfully.

Comment: Show, please, what have to remove minimum to make it working?

Comment: I've added the code that works at the end of my post. The minimum to remove to make it working is the last .channel call.

Comment: You don't compare apples with apples. The `.handle(m -> {` is a one-way endpoint. It isn't going to produce reply. Your concern was about a `@MessagingGateway` and sending a reply back to it. What you have now is different story and doesn't fit an original request.

Comment: Let's come back to the original flow, but this time let's delete `replyChannel = "myFlow.output"` from the `@Gateway` definition and also let's remove `.channel("myFlow.output")` in the flow! This way you should get a reply to the `replyChannel` header. When you configure explicit `replyChannel`, there is no guarantee that you won't have some other subscriber to this channel which is going to "steal" your reply messages.

Comment: I know that the change ended the flow but that was what I was trying to investigate, whether the previous "handle" calls were the culprits of the flow blocking. I tried your solution (not explicitly naming the reply channel of the gateway) and it worked! Thank you :) Could you update your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.